# Is it possible to center userform on VBA Developer main window?

Tags: vba

I'm looking for a way to center a userform on developer winow, not application.

What I have is that:

'''

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Me
        .StartUpPosition = 0
        .Left = Application.VBE.MainWindow.Left '+ (0.25 * Application.VBE.MainWindow.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
        .Top = Application.VBE.MainWindow.Top + (0.25 * Application.VBE.MainWindow.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
    End With
End Sub
```

'''
But this is not working.

Comment: What do you mean by "developer window"? Do you mean VBE (Visual Basic for Application) editor window?

Comment: Yep, that's correct.

Comment: May I know why would you like doing that? The VBE window is hidden anyhow when the form is loaded... Do you only want to play with this, to see if possible?

Comment: Well, you can dock the *Project Explorer* window to the right and *Properties Window* to the left, so your code window is at middle.

Comment: At the time you are trying to set the top and left properties of the userform, it is not yet displayed, and so does not have those values. You can use another event (the Activate one?)

Comment: I have a command bar in VBE editor for VBA developers created (i.e. connection with Git). The userform displayed shows branch I want to do a commit to.

Comment: I'll check with different event.